# vb.net application with sql database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, installation

I am newbie to vb.net and sql. and i tried to search info regarding my query but have not come to solution yet.

I have created vb.net-sql(express 2017) data application, now want to install on client's computer. Regarding installation of sql express is what clients going to do on there computer. so i am going to do database and table creation.

i have created this with first run basis i.e. if application is running for first time(which is in settings). Is it correct way to do it? and also how can i add that database as data source to application?

Comment: Why not add a data file to your project and have it attached to the SQL Server instance on demand? That way, there's nothing be done other than install SQL Server Express.  The data file is already part of your app and gets attached each time the app is run.  Nothing changes within your app other than the connection string, which would use the `AttachDbFilename` attribute to specify the file to be attached.

Comment: In case you aren't aware of it, program data should be stored in your own folder (e.g. company name/program name) within an appropriate folder from the [Environment.SpecialFolder Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.7.2), e.g. ApplicationData, CommonApplicationData, or LocalApplicationData. Those locations will have appropriate file permissions.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I will do reasearch on this but just a quick question, Will it possible to do crud operations on tables then? can i attach tables to datagridviews?

Comment: also will it be able to handle big data?

Comment: I already answered that question: *"Nothing changes within your app other than the connection string"*. You're still using SQL Server Express and the data is still in an MDF data file.  You're still using the same ADO.NET code to interact with the database.  The only difference is that the database gets attached when you run your app and detached when you quit instead of being attached all the time.  If you want multiple clients accessing the same database then it's not an option but your description indicates that that is not the case.

Comment: just to check is this is what you meant: To temporarily attach a database file (.mdf) from the Data Connections node from  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms239722.aspx